# Need help fixing a script for generating texture assignment file in Blender

Tags: python, materials, scripting, unity

Hello Blender community,

I am seeking help with a script I'm working on for generating a texture assignment file in Blender for each .glb file contained in the specified folder. The script is intended to extract material information, including texture paths and filenames, each .glb file.

I intend to use the output as "texture assignments" I'll use to map my textures to the corresponding .fbx files in Unity. (If you know a better approach, do tell! I'm new to Unity). I'm dealing with thousands of .glb files I want to import to Unity in the FBX format and make the characters fit for games and AR.

However, I'm facing some issues with the current implementation.

The script provided below attempts to extract the necessary information, but it's not correctly retrieving the texture paths and filenames for image textures for each node of the principled BSDF.

I've made several attempts to fix it, but I'm still not getting the desired output.

The output I am getting at this point looks like this, it's missing the roughness node, and path and filename for each socket of the BSDF that has an image texture attached:

=== CURRENT OUTPUT ===

Material.001, albedo, ,

Material.001, normal, ,

CowboyBlack, albedo, ,

CowboyBlack, normal, ,

GlassesEyepatch, albedo, ,

GlassesEyepatch, normal, ,

PantsShortsPinkStripes, albedo, ,

PantsShortsPinkStripes, normal, ,

ShirtFrida, albedo, ,

ShirtFrida, normal, ,

============

Here's the script in its current state:

```
import bpy
import os

# Set the input directory
`input_directory = "C:/Users/USER/Models/"`

# Get the list of files in the input directory
`files = os.listdir(input_directory)`

# Loop through the files and extract texture assignments

    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".glb"):
            # Get the full file path
            file_path = os.path.join(input_directory, file)
    
            # Clear existing objects
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
            bpy.ops.object.delete()
    
            # Import the glTF file
            bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath=file_path)
    
            # Create a new file to store the texture assignments
            name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
            with open(os.path.join(input_directory, name + ".txt"), "w") as f:
                # Loop over all objects in the scene
                for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
                    if obj.type == "MESH":
                        # Loop over all material slots in the object
                        for slot in obj.material_slots:
                            material = slot.material
                            if material and material.use_nodes:
                                # Loop over all nodes in the material
                                for node in material.node_tree.nodes:
                                    if node.type == "BSDF_PRINCIPLED":
                                        for input in node.inputs:
                                            if input.name == "Base Color" and input.links:
                                                image_node = input.links[0].from_node
                                                if image_node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE':
                                                    texture_path = bpy.path.abspath(image_node.image.filepath)
                                                    texture_filename = os.path.basename(texture_path)
                                                    f.write(f"{material.name}, albedo, {texture_filename}, {texture_path}\n")
                                            elif input.name == "Roughness" and input.links:
                                                texture_node = input.links[0].from_node
                                                if texture_node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE':
                                                    texture_path = bpy.path.abspath(texture_node.image.filepath)
                                                    texture_filename = os.path.basename(texture_path)
                                                    f.write(f"{material.name}, roughness, {texture_filename}, {texture_path}\n")
                                            elif input.name == "Metallic" and input.links:
                                                texture_node = input.links[0].from_node
                                                if texture_node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE':
                                                    texture_path = bpy.path.abspath(texture_node.image.filepath)
                                                    texture_filename = os.path.basename(texture_path)
                                                    f.write(f"{material.name}, metallic, {texture_filename}, {texture_path}\n")
                                            elif input.name == "Emission" and input.links:
                                                texture_node = input.links[0].from_node
                                                if texture_node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE':
                                                    texture_path = bpy.path.abspath(texture_node.image.filepath)
                                                    texture_filename = os.path.basename(texture_path)
                                                    f.write(f"{material.name}, emission, {texture_filename}, {texture_path}\n")
                                            elif input.name == "Normal" and input.links:
                                                normal_map_node = input.links[0].from_node
                                                if normal_map_node.type == 'NORMAL_MAP' and normal_map_node.inputs['Color'].links:
                                                    texture_node = normal_map_node.inputs['Color'].links[0].from_node
                                                    if texture_node.type =='TEX_IMAGE':
                                                        texture_path = bpy.path.abspath(texture_node.image.filepath)
                                                        texture_filename = os.path.basename(texture_path)
                                                        f.write(f"{material.name}, normal, {texture_filename}, {texture_path}\n")
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could review the script and help me identify the problem. Specifically, I need assistance in ensuring that the script correctly retrieves the texture paths and filenames for each material with an image texture attached to the BSDF.

Any guidance, suggestions, or corrections to the script would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time and assistance[image: typical material setup in the original .glb file]

Comment: Hello ! That's an inverted stairs of if statements if I've ever seen one. Would be much clearer to parse and debug if you used the inverse logic `if obj.type != "MESH": continue` etc, instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. scripting is 1000% new to me, I appreciate your input!